# How can i push a commit to Git

Tags: git-commit, atlassian-sourcetree, git

How can i push a commit to git by using source tree or Terminal from Mac.I tried to find answer on internet but did not get any proper answer.I am totally new to git so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you should read this tutorial. It is well written: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Git/article.html

Comment: If you're totally new to Git, I would recommend investing some time in learning how to use it from the command line. In my experience, learning Git inside a GUI such as SourceTree is a bad idea. Once you understand what's going on "close to the metal", feel free to use a GUI if it makes your workflow easier, but stay away from them at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To literally answer your question:

```
git push [server] [branch]
```

Where server is the remote server name (defaults to origin) and the branch is the one you're working on (usually master if you're working on the main branch).

The following command for instance:

```
git push myserver mybranch
```

Will push all commits on your 'mybranch' branch into server 'myserver'

Having said that, I upped Volker Andres comment because you really should go over a git tutorial to understand the fundamentals.

Comment: is there any difference between gilt or github or it is same.

Comment: Same for github, not familiar with gilt, but if you're using the git cli tool, it is the same